# Can Coulomb force of repulsion split two photons into positron and electron?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, pair-production

imagining a nano device which have ability to squeeze two repelling protons to a point that coulombic force of repulsion is near the maximum, then you direct two photons with energy of 1.0mev at the centre of the two repelling protons. will the photons be splitted into a positron and an electron?.I.e the electron Will be attracted to one of the proton and the remaining positron will be repelled by the other proton and escape.

Comment: A photon does not have charge. It is not affected by coulomb force.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics